# Android Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found in modules

Tags: android, google-places

I am trying to Integrate Google New Place library in my Project as old place library is deprecated. After adding new place library `com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0` it is creating below error.How to resolve this

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found in modules classes.jar 
(com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:16.0.0) and classes.jar 
(com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0)
```

Below is my app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.api.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 27
    versionName "1.5"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    manifestPlaceholders = [HOCKEYAPP_APP_ID: "51a9c4471559421b8d53a07cbb3e3fa0"]
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})

implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', module: 'glide'
}

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta2'
implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0"

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0" 
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.8.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0"

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:1.7.2'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
implementation 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:4.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.krtkush:LinearTimer:v2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'

api "com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.0.0" 
implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'

implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And below is my Project level gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
}

project.ext {
supportVersion = '26.0.1'
googleVersion = '11.8.0'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}


task createWrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = '5.4.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't**

```
implementation ('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.github.bumptech.glide', module: 'glide'
}
```

You can try with

```
implementation "com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0"
```

The Google Play Services version of the Places SDK for Android (i.e. com.google.android.gms:play-services-places) was turned off on July 29, 2019, and is no longer available. A new version of the Places SDK for Android is now available.

**Do**

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.2.0'
}
```

Read [**`Migrating to the New Places SDK`**](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) .

### FYI

You are using very old versions. If you want to use latest then libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade compileSdkVersion to 28 or later.
- Update your app to use Jetpack (AndroidX).

AndroidX replaces the original support library APIs with packages in the androidx namespace. Read official guideline about [**`AndroidX Overview`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).